# What is the differance between dispatch_async and detachNewThreadSelector:@selector()

Tags: crash, autolayout, enumerated-types, mutated

I've faced a crash in my app when using detachNewThreadSelector:@selector() under exception 
***Collection  was mutated while being enumerated***
also there are many of this exception 
***This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.***

then I read about to and realize to use dispath_async instead of detachNewThread selector but i'm looking for a logical reason to doing that if anybody can help me with this . furthermore as we known the detachNewThread it'a also thread!!